# Binding Tuple output to the Gridview

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview

I am developing a web application where in i have a WCF service which interacts with the database using entity framework. I want to get rid of creating Classes for each & every LINQ query
e.g

```
public class Emp
{
 public int CD{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
}


public List<Emp> GetServTypeForPromotionDue()
{
        return (from a in Context.TableName
                    select new Emp{ a.CD, a.NAME });

}
```

for other table & LINQ i have to create a separate class every time. Alternative to this is to use Anonymous method which is not preferable solution. To avoid both the methods I am using Tuple Class where I return List> or List> depending on the return type. This works fine but the problem is I am binding the result of LINQ query directly to a Gridview By default Tuple has properties item1,item2,..& so on. So my griview shows these names are column names so, Is there any way I can change the property name to CD, Name instead of Tuple's Item1, Item2 before binding to grid?

Answer (score 2):

when binding the list, you could use linq:

```
this.grid.DataSource = tupleList.Select(i => new
{
    FirstName = i.Item1,
    LastName = i.Item2,
    CD = i.Item3
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the column names on the GridView and not the tuple.  A tuple is a lightweight type that doesn't support much customization ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386941.aspx)).  If you know what you are binding to the GridView, change the column names by handling the RowDataBound event and checking the RowType of Header, then changing the column names there.